# How to manipulate this result in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a problem for manipulating data in Ansible.
My main goal is to purge ADRCI log.

In a first time, i'm listing the databases that are launched with users Oracle and Grid with the shell module

```
- name: Generate List of databases started with user oracle
  shell: "ps -ef | grep smon | grep -v grep | grep oracle | awk '{print $NF}' | awk -F '_' '{print $NF}'"
  register: list_oracle_bases
```

Then i want to get the homes to purge with an other shell command :

```
- name: Get databases homes
      register: get_homes
      environment:
        ORACLE_SID: "{{ item }}"
        ORAENV_ASK: "NO"
      become: true
      become_user: oracle
      become_method: su
      shell: ". oraenv 1>/dev/null 2>&- && adrci exec='show homes' | grep -v 'ADR Homes:'"
      with_items:
        - "{{ list_oracle_bases.stdout_lines }}"
```

And here comes my problem i've got this result for {{ get_homes }}

```
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
                "_ansible_item_label": "ANSIBLE1",
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_parsed": true,
                "changed": true,
                "cmd": ". oraenv 1>/dev/null 2>&- && adrci exec='show homes' | grep -v 'ADR Homes:'",
                "delta": "0:00:00.028970",
                "end": "2019-03-18 11:29:29.708709",
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": ". oraenv 1>/dev/null 2>&- && adrci exec='show homes' | grep -v 'ADR Homes:'",
                        "_uses_shell": true,
                        "argv": null,
                        "chdir": null,
                        "creates": null,
                        "executable": null,
                        "removes": null,
                        "stdin": null,
                        "warn": true
                    }
                },
                "item": "ANSIBLE1",
                "rc": 0,
                "start": "2019-03-18 11:29:29.679739",
                "stderr": "",
                "stderr_lines": [],
                "stdout": "diag/rdbms/ansible1/ANSIBLE1",
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "diag/rdbms/ansible1/ANSIBLE1"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried to get get_homes.results.stdout_lines but i've got the following error when i want to display it in a debug statement.

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/tmp/sylvain/roles/test/tasks/query.yml': line 59, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n"}
```

What is the correct way to get that stdout_lines ("diag/rdbms/ansible1/ANSIBLE1")  in a variable.

Regards

Sylvain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`results` is an array, because you have created it in a loop (`with_items`). The correct syntax is:

```
get_homes.results[0].stdout_lines
```

for the first and so on for the rest.

In order to get the list of home directories you have to filter the `results` array by the attribute you need. And in the end you have to `flatten` the array of arrays. Here is a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
---
- name: filter
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:

    - shell: |-
        echo ~{{ item }}
      with_items:
        - man
        - lp
        - mail
      register: get_homes
      ignore_errors: true
      changed_when: false

    - debug: var=get_homes

    - set_fact:
        homes: >-
          {{ get_homes.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines') | list | flatten }}

    - debug: var=homes
```